# Child State in UI routing Not Working

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm new to ui-router and states and Im not sure what im doing wrong. I have tried $state.go and ui-sref and neither are working. I'm not sure what the error is but I cant navigate to REQUEST which should be a child to HOME. How can I solve this problem? I can only navigate to it if I a href to the link. If there is more code you need please let me know and I will update it within minutes. Thanks!

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: false,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tab.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'tab-home': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tabs/tab-home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            }
        }

    })

    .state('tab.home.request', {
        url: "/request",
        cache: false,
        views: {
          'tab-home': {
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs/request.html"
           }
        }
    })

;
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');
```

});

Comment: How you are calling to child state using ``$state.go`` or ``ui-sref`` ? can you share that code. Did you checked in browser console if you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors in console. From the home page, $state.go(function) and i tried $state.go(.)  a ui-sref="tab.home.request()"

Comment: ``$state.go`` or ``ui-sref`` should reference a ``state`` , not function. So remove ``()``  and try with ``ui-sref="tab.home.request"`` or ``$state.go("tab.home.request")``

Comment: @SameerK , its loading the page but nothing is displaying.. Btw, thanks for responding.

Comment: Instead of ``tab-home``, try ``tab-home@``. And where and how you have added the reference to ``tab-home`` view??

Comment: I tried that with no luck. I dont know. I started with this "template project" and dont recall doing such. Where should I look? Thanks

Comment: look for either ``ui-view="tab-home"``  or just ``ui-view``. Is it possible to provide fiddle or plunker link ??

Comment: My view just has a title. Would you mind hopping on a really quick google hangout? Im not familiar with fiddle/plunker and It may be easier to share my screen

Comment: Sorry cant make it to hangout.  In the views you need to add ``<div ui-view="tab-home"></div>`` . This where your state respective templates will be loaded.  I guess as you not mentioned, so seeing blank page. Share the view code here and also check out nested states and views @ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router. You will get some idea.